# Java - Keeping track of new list items for later removal?

Tags: java, list

This might seem like a very trivial question but I couldn't come up with an simple solution. I'm sure there is one though.

I have a Check Box Menu Item (a menu item that can be selected or not selected). Whenever it's selected I want it to create and add a new object to a certain list. When it's deselected I want that object to be removed from the list. The object is created on the fly so I have no reference to it.

My question is: how do I remove the object on deselect?

```
final JCheckBoxMenuItem menuItem = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("My Item");                                
menuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        if (menuItem.isSelected()) {
            someList.add(new someClass());                              
        }
        else {
            someList.remove(??);
        }
    }
});
```

I thought of extending JCheckBoxMenuItem class and adding a someClass field to it so I will always have reference to the newly created object. It should technically work, but didn't seem like the most elegant solution...

Comment: Why do you want to add a certain object to a certain list when menuItem is selected ? What is this object ? We must understand what you are trying to do if you want an elegant solution.

Comment: @Vianney Dupoy de Guitard: I have incoming data that is constantly updated. Whenever that data is recieved my program iterates through a list of indicators, each indicator does something a bit different with the data and shows me a result. I have a huge selection of indicators and I dont want them all to be active at once, thus only the ones that are checked will be in the list and the rest should be removed.

Comment: @SpotySpice Then SrikanthLingala reply is correct. Use this : `Map<JCheckBoxMenuItem, MyIndicatorClass>`. And when you need to retrive all indicators, use `myMap.myMap.values()`, it will return a list of `MyIndicatorClass`.

Comment: @VianneyDupoydeGuitard I'm not sure, but beware of memory leaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, I suggest using a `Map`. You can have a corresponding value of the checkbox (for example `checkbox1`) as the key and the newly created object as the value. When you deselect the check box, you can get the `checkbox` name and (in this case checkbox1) and remove it from the `Map`.

Comment: I actually thought about this solution but avoided it at first since I read somewhere a `Map` is not good for iteration. I tried this now using map.values() like @VianneyDupoydeGuitard suggested and it's working perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With the information provided, I'd use my coustom `Action` object to store the created object. Here is an example (very trivial of course, because it just creates a `String`, but it demonstrates the purpose):

```java
JCheckBoxMenuItem item = new JCheckBoxMenuItem(new AbstractAction("...") {
    // Store the object here.
    private String someObject;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JCheckBoxMenuItem source = (JCheckBoxMenuItem) e.getSource();
        if (source.isSelected()) {
            someObject = "Object " + source.getText(); // trivial.
            someList.add(someObject);
        }
        else {
            someList.remove(someObject);
            someObject = null;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I didn't see your answer when I accepted the other answer. I just tried this and it's working as well, thanks. Do you think this is a better solution?

Comment: I don't know enough about your actual problem, but the other solution might introduce unwanted side effects (e.g. memory leaks). I think the benefit of my solution is, that it encapsulates the business logic in the action and does not use a GUI class (as a key) in the business code (the list / map in that case).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are adding a new item to the menu when it is checked and the added entry want to be removed when it is unchecked.Is it so?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [ArrayList.clear()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#clear%28%29)

```
    someList.clear()
```

If you want to remove all element from the list call `clear()` method of the list.

```
@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        if (menuItem.isSelected()) {
            someList.add(new someClass());                              
        }
        else {
            someList.clear();
        }
    }
```

Comment: No, that would clear the whole list, not just remove the de-selected item from the list.